# Ломается таблица при оптимизации Битрикс

Tags: битрикс, myisam

Таблица b_sale_order_change из за неправильного обмена с 1С раздулась за неделю до 2.2 гБ
Я ее почистил скриптом

```
$days = (int)(15);
        $expired = new \Bitrix\Main\Type\DateTime();
        $expired->add('-'.$days.' days');
        $expiredValue = $expired->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        /** @var \Bitrix\Main\DB\Connection $connection */
        $connection = \Bitrix\Main\Application::getConnection();
        /** @var \Bitrix\Main\DB\SqlHelper $sqlHelper */
        $sqlHelper = $connection->getSqlHelper();
        $sqlExpiredDate = $sqlHelper->getDateToCharFunction("'" . $expiredValue . "'");

        if ($connection instanceof \Bitrix\Main\DB\MysqlCommonConnection)
        {
            $query = "DELETE FROM b_sale_order_change WHERE DATE_CREATE > $sqlExpiredDate AND ORDER_ID < 17000";
            if ((int)160000 > 0)
                $query .= " LIMIT ".(int)160000;
            $connection->queryExecute($query);
        }
```

Но ее размер не изменился. прописываю OPTIMIZE TABLE b_sale_order_change в запросе к БД получаю ошибку https://prnt.sc/Qum7_xchaxJ5 Пытаюсь оптимизировать штатными средствами, тоже ломается таблица. Что можете посоветовать для решения данной проблемы.

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)